# Band-Pass Gain of a filter (exercise)

Tags: education

could you help me to find the band-pass gain of the following filter please?

[image]
[image]

The correct expression of pass-band gain hasn't the term \$ C_{B}R_{B} \$ to the numerator (said my professor), instead in my expression there is:

$$G_{PB}=\left(1+\frac {R_{4}}{R_{3}} \right)\left( 1+\frac {R_{2}}{R_{1}} \right)R_{B}C_{B}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That photo hurts my eyes. Please find a way to upload an easier to read schematic. Or redraw it with the in build schematic tool. You might get more help that way.

Comment: Hi @crowie, please tell me what parts of photo aren't clear.

Comment: Its all just very hard to read I'm just suggesting if you want to get help on this site make it clear and easy for people.

Comment: For starters, what is the symbol in parentheses after \$V_{IN}\$?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Grigoryev, I wrote $$V_{IN}\left(s\right)$$ where s is the Laplace's variable.

Comment: Just as a simple starting point: in your expression gain has seconds as unit. Do you think this makes any sense?

Answer (score 1):

- Gnd symbols are too close to parts.
- contrast of grids is same as pencil so hard to read.
- adding brightness and contrast to photo could help us.

I only see one cap, Ca, not two Ca, Cb

The "unstated" assumption in this circuit is that the pulse width expected is much shorter than the time constant T=RaCa so for this condition, assume V(Ca) is a drifting DC voltage dependant on the duty cycle of the pulse and will always be between the pulse max~min levels, so the DC reference level Vlf will change with the signal and its gain is 1+|Av-| which for high gain 1+ can be neglected.  Taking the difference between a signal and it's LPF signal yields the HPF response when both gains are the same (assuming Av>>1 of 2nd stage.  This is an intuitive answer not mathematical such as yours which may be correct for Tpw>RaCa (low frequencies). When we want to simplify gain, we make these assumptions and state them e.g. for f>> 1/(2piRaCa) Av2= +R2/R1

Answer (score 0):

You have two opamp buffers with gain totalling Av = (1 + R2/R1) * (1 + R4/R3) and two first order networks a lowpass RA/CA and a highpass RB/CB.

A first order LPF is G(w) = 1 / (1+jRaCaw)and a highpass is G(w) = jRbCbw/(1+jRbCbw)

Putting it all together I make the overall response (1/(1+jRaCaw)) * jRbCbw/(1+jRbCbw) * (1 + R2/R1) * (1 + R4/R3)

It might be worthwhile multiplying thru by a few complex conjugates to see if you can massage the thing into whatever form the prof wants.

Been a few years since I took this crap back in circuits and systems but it looks right to me.